# Android like iphone style with ActionBar

Tags: android

I'm having trouble using https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android with ActionBar is thus:

[image]

Is with blanks after each item

The result I hope is altogether more or less well

[image]

Comment: Please think about this.  It is anti-Android and against the design patterns.  Apps with toolbars and panels at the bootm are a pain to use because so many phones have soft buttons for back, home etc at the bottom or capacitive buttons.  Please think about redesigning your UI.

Comment: @Simon right, is there any easy and fast way for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redesign my app

Creating a Navigation Drawer
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

ActionBarSherlock
http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Android Design Guidelines
http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Device Art Generator
http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/device-art.html

Android Asset Studio
http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

http://kintek.com.au/blog/portkit-ux-metaphor-equivalents-for-ios-and-android/